# automatize partition creation with fdisk

Tags: linux, python, fdisk

I am using these commands on command line:

```
sudo fdisk /dev/mmcblk1
p
d
w

sudo fdisk /dev/mmcblk1
n
(using all defaults)
w
```

Please is there any option how to automatize this task? Or how to use one liner for this (even for every fdisk command one liner, so two one liners in total)? Or maybe with python?

Comment: Note that `sfdisk` is intended for this sort of automation rather than `fdisk`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply create a file (e.g. `fdisk_cmds`) that contains the commands, as for instance:

```
p
i
    # This is a blank line to select a default response
q

sudo fdisk /dev/mmcblk1 < fdisk_cmds
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use a one liner command (bash):

```
(echo p; echo d; ... ; echo w) | fdisk /dev/mmcblk1
```

To set the default answer use `echo ""` , to answer Yes use `echo "Y"`

Answer (score 1):

Consider SFDisk for this job.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12150116/how-to-script-sfdisk-or-parted-for-multiple-partitions

TIA

Carlos Romel

Answer (score 0):

Firstly use a more appropriate tool.
But if you need to automate this kind of input, use a here-doc:

```bash
sudo fdisk /dev/mmcblk1 <<\EndOfAnswers
p
d
w
q
EndOfAnswers
```

(You can choose whatever single your you like in place of `EndOfAnswers`; you will see a lot of documentation use `EOF` but that's merely a convention. The `\` after `<<` simply makes the first letter of `EndOfAnswers` "quoted", as the shell sees it, which means that no `$` expansions occur in the body of the here-doc; you can get the same effect using `<<'EndOfAnswers'` or `<<"EndOfAnswers"` or even `<<EndOfA\nswers`.)