# bash + how to automate creation of disk partitions in Linux

Tags: bash, shell-script, partition, fdisk, parted

here is example from our rhel server machine

```
lsblk
NAME               MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT

sdb                  8:16   0   20G  0 disk /data/sdb
sdc                  8:32   0   20G  0 disk /data/sdc
sdd                  8:48   0   20G  0 disk /data/sdd
sde                  8:64   0   20G  0 disk /data/sde
sdf                  8:80   0   42G  0 disk
sdg                  8:96   0   42G  0 disk
sdh                  8:112  0   42G  0 disk
```

we want to Create a Disk Partitions for the other disks as `sdf,sdg,sdh` , but all this process should be by bash script and we want to automate the process

first here is example how to create `2` partitions for `sdf` disk ,
so in this example we create two partitions each one will get `10G` size

step 1 ( create partitions when each partition take 10G )

```
parted /dev/sdf
GNU Parted 3.1
Using /dev/sdf
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) mklabel msdos
(parted) mkpart primary 0 10024MB
Warning: The resulting partition is not properly aligned for best performance.
Ignore/Cancel? I
(parted)  mkpart primary 10024MB 20048MB
(parted) quit
Information: You may need to update /etc/fstab.
```

step 2 ( create filesystem ext4 )

```
mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdf1

mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdf2
```

and now we get ( the expected results )

```
lsblk

sdf                  8:80   0   42G  0 disk
├─sdf1               8:81   0  9.3G  0 part
└─sdf2               8:82   0  9.3G  0 part
```

can we automate the `parted` process ?  or maybe by other approach ( for example by `fdisk` ) ?

in order to use this automated process in bash script

reference - https://www.tecmint.com/create-disk-partitions-in-linux/

Comment: What about LVM?

Comment: we cant use lvm on that disks

Comment: I would second @RomeoNinov suggestion but since it is not an option, could this help you ? : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/480369/automatize-partition-creation-with-fdisk Adding the remaining part (mkfsing) being rather trivial. (Take care on error conditions though)

Comment: You do not want, you do not know how, it is forbidden? If this is about software will be the first software I see which do not permit usage of VLM for storage.

Comment: Because I am sure in few months your next question will be: how to extend these filesystems...

Comment: maybe better to post my question in stack-overflow since we need to develop code for that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

parted has an option to use it scripted (--script/-s).

You can issue multiple calls to the program to achieve what you did enter interactively:

```
parted --script /dev/sdf mklabel msdos
parted --script /dev/sdf mkpart primary 1 10024MB
parted --script /dev/sdf mkpart primary 10024MB 20048MB
```

continue with mkfs...

Hint: I started the first partion on 1MB to avoid the warning, which is also the default on many distributions nowadays.

As mentioned by MC68020 as a comment to your question: you should add some error checking code.

Comment: about your note - you mean like this - "parted --script /dev/sdf mkpart primary 1MB 10024MB"               ?

Comment: yes - as you started on 0MB interactively

Comment: by the way is it correct to use - mklabel msdos , in order to create partitions and after that ext or xfs filesystem ?  ( strange to me to use msdos on linux rhel )

Comment: about what you update "parted --script /dev/sdf mkpart primary 1 10024MB"    I see that you wrote 1 - without MB  , is it OK?

Comment: As of the manual "megabytes" is the default (should be read in the IT sense of MiB, i.e. based on 1024).

Comment: "mklabel msdos" specifies the layout of the partition table (also called "disk label"), it has been msdos on all pc type hardware, as a PC's BIOS was not able to read any other partition type. Nowadays GPT would be another option (might already be more popular then msdos)